# BST Output Discrepancies - Seeking Resolution

Tags: c, recursion, binary, binary-search-tree, binary-search

{Add Points: Increase points for a specific member. Subtract Points: Decrease points for a specific member. Remove Member: Delete a member from the system. Search Member: Find a member in the BST and report their points and depth in the tree. Count Alphabetically Prior: Determine the number of members whose names are alphabetically before a given member.}

I have implemented a binary search tree (BST) in C to manage customer data, and I'm experiencing some discrepancies between my program's output and the expected output. I would like to understand what might be causing these differences and how to resolve them.

Here's a brief overview of the issue:

I have a series of input commands, including adding, subtracting, deleting, and searching for customers in the BST. After executing these commands, I compare my program's output to the expected output, and there are differences.

Here is an example of the input and output:

input:

18
add michael 30
add lisa 40
add sophia 45
add max 28
add natalia 60
add lucas 32
add alex 10
add sophia 3
add oliver 20
sub max 30
del michael
sub natalia 28
search alex
search oliver
search michael
sub michael 20
count_smaller max
del max
output:

michael 30
lisa 40
sophia 45
max 28
natalia 60
lucas 32
alex 10
sophia 48
oliver 20
max 0
michael deleted
natalia 32
alex 10 0
oliver 20 4
michael not found
michael not found
6
max deleted
sophia 48
lisa 40
lucas 32
natalia 32
oliver 20
alex 10

my output:
michael 30
lisa 40
sophia 45
max 28
natalia 60
lucas 32
alex 10
sophia 48
oliver 20
max 0
michael deleted
natalia 32
alex not found
oliver 20 4
michael not found
michael 0
6
max deleted
sophia 48
lisa 40
lucas 32
natalia 32
oliver 20
alex 10

```
#define MAXLEN 19

typedef struct customer {
    char name[MAXLEN + 1];
    int points;
} customer;

typedef struct treenode {
    customer* cPtr;
    struct treenode* left;
    struct treenode* right;
} treenode;

// Function Declarations
treenode* createNewNode(customer* c);
treenode* insertNode(treenode* root, customer* c, int addPoints, int* isNew);
treenode* findNode(treenode* root, char* name);
int findNodeWithDepth(treenode* root, char* name, int* depth);
void updatePoints(treenode* root, char* name, int points);
treenode* deleteNode(treenode* root, char* name);
treenode* minValueNode(treenode* node);
int countBefore(treenode* root, char* name);
void inOrderCollect(treenode* root, customer** arr, int* index);
customer* readCustomer(char* name, int points);
int compareCustomers(const void* a, const void* b);
void sortCustomers(customer** customers, int n);

// Function Definitions
treenode* createNewNode(customer* c) {
    treenode* newNode = (treenode*)malloc(sizeof(treenode));
    newNode->cPtr = c;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

treenode* insertNode(treenode* root, customer* c, int addPoints, int* isNew) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        *isNew = 1;
        return createNewNode(c);
    }
    int cmp = strcmp(c->name, root->cPtr->name);
    if (cmp < 0) {
        root->left = insertNode(root->left, c, addPoints, isNew);
    } else if (cmp > 0) {
        root->right = insertNode(root->right, c, addPoints, isNew);
    } else {
        *isNew = 0;
        root->cPtr->points += addPoints;
    }
    return root;
}

treenode* findNode(treenode* root, char* name) {
    if (root == NULL) return NULL;
    if (strcmp(name, root->cPtr->name) == 0)
        return root;
    else if (strcmp(name, root->cPtr->name) < 0)
        return findNode(root->left, name);
    else
        return findNode(root->right, name);
}

int findNodeWithDepth(treenode* root, char* name, int* depth) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return -1;  // Not found
    }
    int cmp = strcmp(name, root->cPtr->name);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        return root->cPtr->points;
    } else if (cmp < 0) {
        (*depth)++;
        return findNodeWithDepth(root->left, name, depth);
    } else {
        (*depth)++;
        return findNodeWithDepth(root->right, name, depth);
    }
}

treenode* minValueNode(treenode* node) {
    treenode* current = node;
    while (current && current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;
    return current;
}

treenode* deleteNode(treenode* root, char* name) {
    if (root == NULL) return root;

    if (strcmp(name, root->cPtr->name) < 0)
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, name);
    else if (strcmp(name, root->cPtr->name) > 0)
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, name);
    else {
        if (root->left == NULL) {
            treenode* temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        } else if (root->right == NULL) {
            treenode* temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        treenode* temp = minValueNode(root->left); // Changed to left subtree
        root->cPtr = temp->cPtr;
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, temp->cPtr->name);
    }
    return root;
}

int countBefore(treenode* root, char* name) {
    if (root == NULL) return 0;
    if (strcmp(name, root->cPtr->name) > 0)
        return 1 + countBefore(root->left, name) + countBefore(root->right, name);
    else
        return countBefore(root->left, name);
}

void inOrderCollect(treenode* root, customer** arr, int* index) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        inOrderCollect(root->left, arr, index);
        arr[*index] = root->cPtr;
        (*index)++;
        inOrderCollect(root->right, arr, index);
    }
}

customer* readCustomer(char* name, int points) {
    customer* c = (customer*)malloc(sizeof(customer));
    strcpy(c->name, name);
    c->points = points;
    return c;
}

int compareCustomers(const void* a, const void* b) {
    customer* custA = *(customer**)a;
    customer* custB = *(customer**)b;
    if (custA->points == custB->points)
        return strcmp(custA->name, custB->name);
    return custB->points - custA->points;
}

void sortCustomers(customer** customers, int n) {
    qsort(customers, n, sizeof(customer*), compareCustomers);
}

// Main Function
int main() {
    int n, i, points, depth, isNew;
    char command[15], name[MAXLEN + 1];
    treenode* root = NULL;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s", command);
        if (strcmp(command, "add") == 0) {
            scanf("%s %d", name, &points);
            customer* c = readCustomer(name, points);
            isNew = 0;
            root = insertNode(root, c, points, &isNew);
            if (!isNew) free(c); // Free the customer if not inserted
            printf("%s %d\n", name, findNode(root, name)->cPtr->points);
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "sub") == 0) {
            scanf("%s %d", name, &points);
            treenode* node = findNode(root, name);
            if (node != NULL) {
                node->cPtr->points = node->cPtr->points > points ? node->cPtr->points - points : 0;
            }
            printf("%s %d\n", name, node ? node->cPtr->points : 0);
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "del") == 0) {
            scanf("%s", name);
            if (findNode(root, name)) {
                root = deleteNode(root, name);
                printf("%s deleted\n", name);
            } else {
                printf("%s not found\n", name);
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "search") == 0) {
            scanf("%s", name);
            depth = 0;
            points = findNodeWithDepth(root, name, &depth);
            if (points >= 0) {
                printf("%s %d %d\n", name, points, depth);
            } else {
                printf("%s not found\n", name);
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(command, "count_smaller") == 0) {
            scanf("%s", name);
            int count = countBefore(root, name);
            printf("%d\n", count);
        }
    }

    customer** customers = (customer**)malloc(sizeof(customer*) * n);
    int index = 0;
    inOrderCollect(root, customers, &index);
    sortCustomers(customers, index);

    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", customers[i]->name, customers[i]->points);
        free(customers[i]);
    }
    free(customers);
    // Free the tree here if necessary
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the missing includes.